# Avoid duplicate form loading in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 windows forms.Both Form1 and form2 have a button. When I click the button in form1 it shows form2 and vice versa. But it create a duplicate form when I click button on each time. How to avoid it. please tell me. My code is given below.

**Form1:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Show();
}
```

**Form2:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    f1.Show();
}
```

Comment: Don't `new` up a new form everytime. Create them as hidden (`OnLoad`) and only `.Show()` on the button click

Comment: because you are creating new instance of form each time you clicking button

Comment: how to do it? please tell me...

Comment: *new* creates a *new* instance. You need to look into how to "reference a form from another form"

Answer (score 2):

just use this method common and pass parameter like 'this' when button click

```
 public bool formIsExist(Form frmOpen)
    {
        FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;

        foreach (Form frm in fc)
        {
            if (frm.Name == frmOpen.Name)
            {
               return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This determines whether the form is already open, but it does not provide a way to bring it to the front.

Comment: if want to bring it front then add `frm.BringToFront();`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating a new form each time you click the button.
To solve this problem You could make your form static.

```
    static Form1 form = new Form1();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form.Show();
    }
```

Comment: What if the form is closed?

Answer (score 0):

My solution, you can try

**Form1**

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
                bool present = false;

                foreach (Form frm in fc)
                {

                    if (frm.Name == "Form2")
                    {
                        present = true;
                    }
                }

                if (!present)
                {
                    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
                    f2.Show();
                }
            }
```

**Form2**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
            bool present = false;

            foreach (Form frm in fc)
            {

                if (frm.Name == "Form1")
                {
                    present = true;
                }
            }

            if (!present)
            {
                Form1 f1 = new Form1();
                f1.Show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean not working ? do you want form1 disappear after form2 show an vise verse ?

Comment: my purpose is when i click button in form1 then form2 will be open. Similarly when i click button in form2 it shows  form1 again. But here while i am clicking button in form2 it doesn't show anything.

Comment: it dosen't show anything because a instance of form1 is already open, you ask not to create a duplicate, if open again then it will be duplicate so it doesent open another one

Comment: i want to go back to that form1 again. But, doesn't opened a duplicate form. Here in my code what happens is , when i click button each time it shows new and new forms. So many forms are running in my application.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to determine whether the target form is already there and in that case, open it.

For example, in `Form1` do this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < Application.OpenForms.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Application.OpenForms[i] is Form2)
        {
            f2 = Application.OpenForms[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (f2 == null)
        f2 = new Form2();

    f2.Show();
}
```

To make a common method for all forms, you could try this:

```
public static T GetForm<T>() where T : Form
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Application.OpenForms.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Application.OpenForms[i] is T)
            return (T)Application.OpenForms[i];
    }

    return null;
}
```

And call it like:

```
Form2 f2 = GetForm<Form2>();
if (f2 == null) f2 = new Form2();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mostafiz' answer is almost correct. It just misses the code to show the found present form. (Sorry, do not yet have 50 reputation to write this as a comment)

Try this code:

Form1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form form = null;

    //search all opened forms for one with name "Form2"
    foreach( Form frm in Application.OpenForms )
        if( frm.Name == "Form2" ) //this requires Form2 to be named "Form2"
        {
            form = frm;
            break;
        }

    //if no opened Form2 was found, create a new one
    if( form == null )
        form = new Form2();

    form.Show();
}
```

Form2:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form form = null;

    //search all opened forms for one with name "Form1"
    foreach( Form frm in Application.OpenForms )
        if( frm.Name == "Form1" ) //this requires Form1 to be named "Form1"
        {
            form = frm;
            break;
        }

    //if no opened Form1 was found, create a new one
    if( form == null )
        form = new Form1();

    form.Show();
}
```